# Ultimate Skyrim crashes after character creation

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I create my character, name him, and the game freezes for about 10 seconds before completely crashing. Does anyone have any ideas on what I might've done wrong? Are there any error logs that would be helpful? Let me know where to find them and I'll post them.

Comment: Do you use mods, and, if so, what is your load order? Do you use SKSE? Are you on PC or console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are crashing after racemenu, it's probably `ENB` related. I fixed this issue with mine by reinstalling the `ENB binary files`. Did you try giving that a shot yet?